# Problema con jQuery keypress() en .ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Tengo un formulario en `.ASP` con `Visual Basic` y en un `TextBox` quiero controlar lo que se escribe en él controlando otras cosas, pongo el código y explico:

```
$('#CantidadTextBox').on(function () {
    var LecturaB = $('select[name=LecturaItemAuB]').val();
    var LecturaF = $('select[name=LecturaItemAuF]').val();

    KeyPress: function (event, keyCode, char) {
        if (LecturaB == 'True' && My.QueryString('tipo') == 'b') {
        alert("funciona con lectura B");

            if ($('#CantidadTextBox').text() != "") {
                alert("entra al if");
                $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
            }

        }
        if (LecturaF == 'True' && My.QueryString('tipo') == 'f') {
            $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Al estar sobre el `TextBox` que tiene `ID` `CantidadTextBox` voy a buscar  dos variables, teniendo esos datos al escribir un número quiero controlar que, dependiendo de la primera comprobación si el campo es diferente de vacío se vaya a otro `TextBox`.

Yo veo bien el código, pero al correr la aplicación se cae en la linea:

> KeyPress: function (event, keyCode, char)

y además me salta un error de:

> (JS) Se esperaba un identificador.

Estoy aplicando mal la propiedad **`KeyPress`**??

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Que tienes en `My.QueryString` ?

Comment: Cambiar la funcion para que sea directamente a `keypress` asi: `('#CantidadTextBox').keypress(function( event, keyCode, char ) {`

Comment: el *My.QueryString* captura una variable, es como un get, creo que es algo de .asp que todavía no entiendo bien jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno modifico mi respuesta, y te explico lo que hice,primero no creo que te funcione con el `keypress` y con el `keydown` ya que estos eventos no toman el valor del primer pres , por eso cambie la función y y agrega el **`onkeyup`** al campo que llama a la función con la que validas

Prueba el snippet.

```js
function  ValidarNumero(elemento) {
    var LecturaB = 'true';
    var LecturaF = 'true';
    
        if (LecturaB == 'true' &&  $('#QueryString').val() == 'b') {
        alert("funciona con lectura B");

            if (!isNaN(parseInt(elemento.value))) {
            
                $('#CodigoTextBox').val(elemento.value)
                $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
                $('#CantidadTextBox').val("");
                
            }

        }
        if (LecturaF == 'true' && $('#QueryString').val() == 'f') {
            $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
        }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="QueryString" placeholder="QueryString">

<input type="text" id="CantidadTextBox"  onkeyup="ValidarNumero(this)">

<!--este es tu textbox solo le agregas el event onkeyup -->
<asp:TextBox ID="CantidadTextBox" runat="server" Width="50px"
    data-charallow="0123456789," data-required="true" 
    data-nextfoco="CodigoTextBox" 
    data-required-message="Falta ingresar la cantidad" EnableTheming="True" 
    Font-Names="Agency FB" Font-Size="20pt" Height="43px" Enabled="False"
    onkeyup="ValidarNumero(this)">
</asp:TextBox>

<input type="text" id="CodigoTextBox">
```

Comment: mi idea es que si yo escribo en el campo CantidadTextBox, lo que escriba mientras LecturaB sea true el foco se pase a CodigoTextBox. cosa que no pasa al probar tu código

Comment: Según tu código , lo que quieres hacer es que si al seleccionar en un **DropDownList**  o **select**  como lo quieras llamar,  seleccionas **"B"** y en el campo `CantidadTextBox` haya un numero te pase el foco a otro campo ?

Comment: claro, lo que busco es evuitar que la gente pueda escribir números en este campo mientras el **LecturaB** sea verdadero y el **$('#QueryString').val()** sea igual a **b**. Si trata de escribir algo el foco cambia al CodigoTextBox

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda mira la nueva respuesta, es esto lo que quieres lograr  ?

Comment: Hola, buenos días, me queda la duda en cómo tengo que llamar a esta función, no me quedó muy claro con tu explicación del keyPress, keydown, onkeypup, lo tengo así [LINK](https://codeshare.io/5eebL9). Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda voy a editar la respuestacon tu codigo

Comment: Muchas Gracias y disculpa por molestarte tanto

Comment: Tranquilo, para eso estamos. @SebastiánMiranda

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el evento `keypress` de `JQuery`, este evento retorna varias propiedades, como por ejemplo el valor `keyCode`, y el valor `key` que puede representar tu `char`, solamente lo mandas llamar dentro del evento como `event.keyCode` y `event.key.`

**Por ejemplo:**

```
$('#CantidadTextBox').keypress(function(event){  
    var LecturaB = $('select[name=LecturaItemAuB]').val();
    var LecturaF = $('select[name=LecturaItemAuF]').val();
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    var char = event.key;

        if (LecturaB == 'True' && My.QueryString('tipo') == 'b') {
        alert("funciona con lectura B");

            if ($('#CantidadTextBox').text() != "") {
                alert("entra al if");
                $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
            }

        }
        if (LecturaF == 'True' && My.QueryString('tipo') == 'f') {
            $('#CodigoTextBox').focus();
        }    
});
```

Espero sea lo que necesitas.